# Azure Devops Pipeline to run Powershell task in ci/cd yaml script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Im new to Azure devops just learning the process how it works im writting a basic script in pipeline but unable to get the value of parameter, only Hello is printing  it should print **Hello World!** anything i have missed here assist me with this

```
trigger:
- main

parameters:
- name: name
  type: string
  default: 'World'

variables:
 - name: ${{ parameters.name }}   

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $env:name
      echo "Hello, $name!"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is a useless repetition of the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to convey information about the content to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. For some suggestions about writing a good title, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) you can echo both variables and parameters, just in a different format you're used to:

```
echo "Hello, ${{ parameters.name }}"
```

You don't need to convert the parameter to a variable.